# Finding the pdf of $Z=X+Y$ given the pdfs of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Given that $X ,Y$ has the following joint pdf: $$f (x, y) = x + y , \qquad 0 \leq x \leq 1, \quad 0\leq y \leq 1$$
Let $Z = X+Y$.  I need help in finding the pdf $f(z)$ of $Z$.

*EDIT [by Srivatsan]:* Changed the definition of $Z$ from $Z = x+y$ to $Z = X+Y$ in the title and the post.

Comment: You must have meant $Z=X+Y$ rather than $Z=x+y$.

Comment: Hint:  Let $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$ be a fixed number.  Compute $P\{Z \leq \alpha\}$.  Repeat for $P\{Z \leq \beta\}$ where $1 \leq \beta \leq 2$.  You will need to do double integrals to find these probabilities.  Draw pictures to help you figure out the limits of the double integrals.  Then find $f_Z(z)$ by differentiating $F_Z(z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the joint pdf corresponds to a measure (using [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)):
$$
  \mathrm{d} F_{X,Y}(x,y) = (x+y) [ 0 \leq x \leq 1] [0 \leq y \leq 1] \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d} y
$$
Let's perform a change of variables $z=x+y$ and $ w = \frac{y-x}{2}$. The corresponding Jacobian equals 1, and we get:
$$
 \mathrm{d} F_{X,Y}(x(z,w),y(z,w)) = z \left[ 0 \leq z \leq 2, |w| \leq \min\left( \frac{z}{2}, 1-\frac{z}{2}\right) \right] \mathrm{d} z \mathrm{d} w
$$ 
It is now easy to integrate over $w$, giving you the marginal measure:
$$
   \mathrm{d} F_Z(z) = z \min\left( z, 2-z \right) \left[ 0 \leq z \leq 2 \right] \,\mathrm{d} z = f_Z(z) \mathrm{d} z
$$